# How to change user roles when a custom button is clicked?

Tags: wordpress, button, woocommerce, cart, user-roles

I need to change the "Add to Cart" button for specific products already purchased to a button saying "Select" that changes the user's role according to the specific product.

Once a user makes a purchase from the store, I have it set up so that they acquire a role according to the product ID they purchased. If they purchase a different product, their old role is removed and new role added reflective of the new product ID.

After a one-time purchase, users should have permanent access to switch roles as they like without repurchasing. I have successfully managed to change the "Add to Cart" button to say "Select" and can redirect to a new link, but I still need to change the role of the user still when they click it, potentially on the linked page.

```
// Changing the Add to Cart for specific purchased products

add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'customizing_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function customizing_add_to_cart_button( $link, $product ){

    $bought = false;

    if( is_user_logged_in() ){

        $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
            'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
            'post_status' => 'wc-completed' // Only orders with status "completed"
        ) );

        // Going through each current customer orders
        foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
            $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order->ID );
            // Going through each current customer order items
            foreach($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_values){
                if($item_values['product_id'] == $product->id){
                    $bought = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if($bought){

         // for the product ID 317 
        if( $product->id == 317 ){
            $add_to_cart_url = site_url('/members/me/profile/collection');
            $button_text =  __('Select 317', 'woocommerce');

        }

        // for the product ID 311 
        if( $product->id == 311){
            $add_to_cart_url = site_url('/members/me/profile/collection');
            $button_text =  __('Select 311', 'woocommerce');

        }


    } else {

        $add_to_cart_url = $product->add_to_cart_url();
        $button_text =  $product->add_to_cart_text();

    }

    $link = sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="button product_type_%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $add_to_cart_url ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
        esc_html( $button_text )
    );

    return $link;
}
```

I think there may need to be a separate function that allows for removing the current product role and adding the new one on the landing page based on which product button was used. I am not the best at php, first project so let me know if there is a way to achieve this! Thank you.

Comment: You can use ajax for this, ajax is best way to use js events with php code.

Comment: Sorry for lack of experience, but how do I implement Ajax here. I currently have php functions and short codes [rolechange-317] [rolechange-311] that changes a user’s role when they land on a page, but is there a way to hook and run the short code based on which button they used in the code above to get there?

Comment: Please check http://nivadeep.co.nf/#wordpres-ajax

Comment: This will help you to add ajax in your website, you can you Jquery event like click event with ajax.